# Spring Security with CAS rest (Direct login)

Tags: java, spring, security, authentication, cas

I have a question about using Spring CAS Service.
Everything is working so far. (Server & Client)

But I need to authenticate without the redirect to the cas login site.
So I need a direct login, to request some data from the service API.

I added the CAS Rest authentification to my cas server.

And now I can request a TGT ticket via:

```
curl --data "username=demo&password=demo" https://cas/cas/v1/tickets
```

After that, I can request a service ticket via TGT Ticket:

```
curl --data "service=https://serviceHost/web/" https://cas/cas/v1/tickets/TGT-9-ODzpFwQF7dwxSrtCPkR3ZySfnMroyp
```

I see in the CAS Server logs, the user is authendicated with this service ticket.

But when I try to request some URL from my service
via:

```
curl https://serviceHost/web/api/getAuftraege?ticket=ST-21-4ucWgqnFTSyYT
```

I am redirected to the cas login site.

I think my webapp is not interpreting my "ticket" param.

Do I have to put some kind of resolver into the config of my webapp?

Do I need some dependencies for my Spring web Application?

Comment: I think you missed to validate service ticket : try after the request  service TGT `curl -X GET /cas/p3/serviceValidate?service=https://serviceHost/web/&ticket=[response of the TGT request]`

Comment: Hmm, it tells me, the Ticket is invald. <cas:authenticationFailure code="INVALID_TICKET">Ticket &#39;ST-104-QFat4SiIkGUi1MqjItqlYvr8z78-tc1&#39; wurde nicht anerkannt</cas:authenticationFailure>

Comment: that's weired make sur you pass the Service Ticket from the st TGT request  !

Comment: yes, it should be the ST- ticket, or?

Comment: i also tryed it with escapes %2F for /, same result

Comment: Yes it's ST generated ticket , Wich version of cas you're using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171997/discussion-between-boo-berrita-and-yingyang).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 years ago I had a task that I should wrote a java client for cas login:

```
public boolean login(String service, String jsessionid) throws IOException {
    tgt = getTicketGrantingTicket(username, password);
    String st = getServiceTicket(service, tgt);
    commitJsessionid(service, jsessionid, st);
    this.jsessionid = jsessionid;
    return true;
}

public String getTicketGrantingTicket(String username, String password) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    params.put("username", username);
    params.put("password", password);
    HttpURLConnection conn = restClient.post(casUrl + "/v1/tickets", params);
    StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String input;
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
        responseBuilder.append(input);
    }
    in.close();

    String response = responseBuilder.toString();
    if (conn.getResponseCode() == 400) {
        throw new AuthenticationException("bad username or password");
    }
    String location = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
    return location;
}

public String getServiceTicket(String service, String tgt) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    params.put("service", service + "/j_acegi_security_check");

    HttpURLConnection conn = restClient.post(tgt, params);
    StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String input;
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
        responseBuilder.append(input);
    }
    in.close();

    String response = responseBuilder.toString();

    return response;
}

public String commitJsessionid(String service, String jsessionid, String st) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = restClient.get(service + "/j_acegi_security_check;jsessionid=" + jsessionid + "?ticket=" + st);
    StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String input;
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
        responseBuilder.append(input);
    }
    in.close();

    String response = responseBuilder.toString();

    return response;
}

public boolean validateServiceTicket(String service, String st) throws IOException {
    HttpURLConnection conn = restClient.get(casUrl + "/proxyValidate?ticket=" + st + "&service=" + service + "/j_acegi_security_check");
    StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String input;
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
        responseBuilder.append(input);
    }
    in.close();

    String response = responseBuilder.toString();

    return response.toString().contains("authenticationSuccess");
}
```

and you can call your rest service with this method:

```
    public String callRestExample(String service, String rest) throws IOException {
    String url = service;
    if (jsessionid != null)
        url += "/services/" + rest + ";jsessionid=" + jsessionid;

    HttpURLConnection conn = restClient.get(url);
    StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    String input;
    while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
        responseBuilder.append(input);
    }
    in.close();

    String response = responseBuilder.toString();
    if (jsessionid == null) {
        int index = response.indexOf("jsessionid");
        jsessionid = response.substring(index + 13, index + 45);
        tgt = getTicketGrantingTicket(username, password);
        String st = getServiceTicket(service, tgt);
        commitJsessionid(service, jsessionid, st);
        callRestExample(service, rest);
    }

    return response;
}
```